# send multiple CoreData objects to MySQL database

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, core-data, export

I am facing something I cannot sort out despite some interesting posts. I do not know how I can export multiple entries stored as Core data NSObjects to a MySQL database running on my mac. Everything is fine for an only entry but I don't know the best way to add multiples entries (one big dictionary vs multiples requests with a one item-containg dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray *allPersons = [[PersonStore sharedStore] allPersons];

for (Person *element in allPersons) {
    [dictionary setValue:element.firstName forKey:@"firstname"];
    [dictionary setValue:element.lastName forKey:@"lastname"];
    [dictionary setValue:element.dateOfBirth forKey:@"dateOfBirth"];

    // ---> here I am lost. How can I append all the different Person onjects into the data to the body I am going to send in a single run? Multiple requests versus a big one?
}

NSError *error;

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];

NSString *urlString = @"http://my_name.local:8888/postPerson.php";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:data]; //set the data as the post body

[urlRequest addValue:@"postValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *dataRaw, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:dataRaw
                          options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", json];

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView * av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Checking permissions:\n\nErreur:\n%@.\n", error] message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [av show];
    }

    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:result message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [av show];

}];

[dataTask resume];
```

}

I insert my question in the code...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It depends whether your `postPerson` php script can cope with multiple persons in a single post.

Comment: I can edit my PHP script if needed. I was wondering if it is better to have a big dictionary (with an array made of all my Person objects inside) or a dictionary for each Person object?

Comment: But I don't know how I can manage many dictionaries with my iOS NSURLSession without the need to call the method many times

Comment: I would build an array of dictionaries, which `NSJSONSerialisation` should be able to encode as JSON.  Then code your PHP script to parse the JSON correctly - it should be straight forward to loop through all the elements of the array in the JSON.